# How to change the template for bundled product options in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, stock, bundle

In `price-bundle.js` there is a function:

```
        ...
    _applyOptionNodeFix: function applyOptionNodeFix(options) {
        ...
```

Which cleans up the dropdowns and templates the data.

I would like to add to this template to include the inventory number on the stock.

I ave managed to add the inventory to the options in the select on the intial server response so I would now want to add that value to `toTemplate.data`.

I also want to change the template so it looks like:

`"<%- data.label %><% if (data.finalPrice.value) { %> +<%- data.finalPrice.formatted %><% } %>" ( <%- data.stock_level_label %>)`

instead of

`"<%- data.label %><% if (data.finalPrice.value) { %> +<%- data.finalPrice.formatted %><% } %>"`

How can this be done?

The full function is:

```
/**
 * Helper to fix issue with option nodes:
 *  - you can't place any html in option ->
 *    so you can't style it via CSS
 * @param {jQuery} options
 * @private
 */
_applyOptionNodeFix: function applyOptionNodeFix(options) {
    var config = this.options,
        format = config.priceFormat,
        template = config.optionTemplate;
    template = mageTemplate(template);
    options.filter('select').each(function (index, element) {
        var $element = $(element),
            optionId = utils.findOptionId($element),
            optionName = $element.prop('name'),
            optionType = $element.prop('type'),
            optionConfig = config.optionConfig && config.optionConfig.options[optionId].selections;

        $element.find('option').each(function (idx, option) {
            var $option,
                optionValue,
                toTemplate,
                prices;

            $option = $(option);
            optionValue = $option.val();

            if (!optionValue && optionValue !== 0) {
                return;
            }

            toTemplate = {
                data: {
                    label: optionConfig[optionValue] && optionConfig[optionValue].name
                }
            };
            prices = optionConfig[optionValue].prices;

            _.each(prices, function (price, type) {
                var value = +(price.amount);
                value += _.reduce(price.adjustments, function (sum, x) {
                    return sum + x;
                }, 0);
                toTemplate.data[type] = {
                    value: value,
                    formatted: utils.formatPrice(value, format)
                };
            });

            $option.html(template(toTemplate));
        });
    });
},
```